# Error message from install.packages() - wayward continuation line

Tags: r, installation, package

With RStudio and running under Windows, my effort to install the `textreg` package encountered a strange error:

```
> install.packages("textreg")
Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 17116 != reported length 200
Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 17116 != reported length 200
Error in install.packages : Found continuation line starting '  <title>Marriott â€“ ...' at begin of record.
```

Does the error tell me that something in the package has the gremlin  ....?  Can I fix that problem at my end or should I write Luke Miratrix, the maintainer?  Or am I doing something foolish?

Thank you

Comment: The windows binary is [not available](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textreg/index.html), but I can install with `install.packages("textreg", type="source")`.

Comment: I'd suggest writing to the maintainer. It's worth noting that if you look at the CRAN page, you'll see textreg binaries have not been built for windows, which can indicate the library is not supported or expected to build there.

Comment: @Roland, the type="source" argument worked.  Thank you.  I did not know about that option.  Do you want to make your comment an answer so I can accept it, and perhaps explain why the additional argument made the difference?  I think I will also drop a note to the maintainer.  Thanks, also to Oliver Keyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows binary is currently not available from CRAN and that `install.packages` didn't report that indicates that the mirror is not up-to-date. However, I was able to build the package from source on my Win7 system. Thus, you can use `install.packages("textreg", type="source")`.

Answer (score 1):

The windows binary is currently not available from CRAN because the package failed the windows test suite (for reasons as yet unknown).  I am working on fixing that error and apologize for any inconvenience.  That being said, installing as mentioned above via

`install.packages("textreg", type="source")`

will give you a working package.  If you get it to crash, please contact me (the maintainer) with details.

Also note that a further mild issue is the static vignette "bathtub" does not show up on CRAN, but is in the inst/doc directory of the package.  You can also test the package with the `testthat` package using the inst/test/testthat folder in the package.

Comment: The windows binary is now on CRAN.