# Error installing R package forecast

Tags: r, error-handling, install.packages

Im trying to install the "forecast" package in R and I keep getting the following error

`Error in install.packages : Found continuation line starting '        <link rel="s ...' at begin of record`.

I'm running R 3.2.2 Windows 64 bit

I've tried these, I get the same error

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/forecast_7.1.tar.gz ",repos=NULL, dependencies = TRUE)

install.packages("forecast", dep = T, lib="C:/Projects/Consumption curves/Rpackages")

install.packages("forecast", type="source")
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506116/error-message-from-install-packages-wayward-continuation-line.  In fact, https://www.google.com/?client=ubuntu#channel=fs&q=Found+continuation+line+starting

Comment: I tried that , Not working.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using. Can you install any other packages?

Comment: Have  tried the above. Looks like I'm getting the same issue trying to install any new package, however, already installed packages are working fine